# how to extend method of the super class with custom content

Tags: java

I am looking for the solution how extend method of the super class with custom content.

for example I have a super class

```
class A{

  public  A(){
    boolean ok = doSomeInitialWork();

    if(ok){
        specialMehtod();
    }
  }

  specialMehtod(){
     System.out.print("HEllO");
  }
}
```

so my class A does some "init" things and then calls specialMehtod(). Now I would like to have `class B extends A`  and add some other code to specialMehtod(). Something like:

```
Class B extends A{

    B(){
        super();
    }

    specialMehtod(){
       System.out.print("BBBBB");      
    }
}
```

But if I do so, I call `a.SpecialMethod()` expizit, and actually I only want to "add" `System.out.print("BBBBB");` to specialMethod(), so that it still get called from constructor of A.

What I want to achieve, is that finaly I could do in my main class

`new B();`

ant the output would be. 
`HELLO
BBBBB`

because B() calls constructor of A(), which calls `A.specialMethod()` extended by B.specialMethod();

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to do but if you override the someSpecialTask method in B it should work no?

Comment: You either inherit method as is, or override it. All answers below give you solution for this problem without answering your question, unfortunately.

Comment: I edit my question, maybe its now more clear what I would like to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to so something like this:

```
public abstract class A{
    public abstract void anotherMethod();

    public A(){
        // some stuff..
        specialMethod();
    }

    private final void specialMethod(){
        System.out.println("specialMethod");
        anotherMethod();
    }
}

public class B extends A{
     public B(){
         super();
     }

     public void anotherMethod(){
         System.out.println("anotherMethod");
     }
}
```

This way you force your extending class to implement the method `anotherMethod()` and this method is called from your abstract class `A`. If your extending class does not need to do anything in `anotherMethod()`, you can just let the method body empty.

---

As mentioned in the comments of your question, you have to either inherit or override the method. When overriding a method, you have to call the super-method `super.someMethod();` explicitly or when inheriting, you can not add additional functionality to the given method.
So to come with your example, if you don't implement `specialMethod()` in `B`, it will print out "HELLO", since `A` has an implementation for the method, but `B` does not. If you override the method like you are doing in the example in class `B`:

```
specialMethod(){
    System.out.println("BBBBB");
}
```

It will have the effect that "HELLO" will not be printed out. In this case, the constructor of `A` will directly call `B.specialMethod()` (on the instance of the B Object). If you wan't `A.specialMethod()` to be called, you have to explicitly call it. So, no, you can not 'add functionality' to a method implemented in the super-class without explicitly calling `super.specialMethod()`.

For this reason, I have constructed the example above as a workaround. Please note that I have updated the code. With that example, if you call `new B();`, the output will be:

```
specialMethod
anotherMethod
```

And with this workaround, the extending class does not explicitly have to call `super.specialMethod()`, but it must implement `anotherMethod()`. Additionally, by making `specialMethod` a `final` method, `B` is not allowed to override `specialMethod`.

Comment: thank you for explaining. I tried it and it worked perfectly. btw, I am using Eclipse  and it auto-suggest me to add anotherMethod() to B class, and put it with @Override annotation. Is this annotation just to have better view of overridden methods?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what all the benefits of the @Override annotations are, but it's definitely easier to read. It might be an advantage when creating JavaDoc and maybe also if you are using [java.lang.reflect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `abstract` method in `A`. Like this -

```
public class A{
   public abstract specialMethod();
}
```

Then when `B` extends `A`, `B` have to implement the `specialMethod()` by its own.